# Execute selenise runner on Firefox

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide, selenium-firefoxdriver, geckodriver

I am using [selenise runner](https://github.com/vmi/selenese-runner-java) to run script in different browsers.

I am using this config file:

```
firefox: C://Users/Desktop/geckodriver.exe
highlight: Yes
baseurl: https://example.com/
set-speed: 1000
timeout: 30000
driver: firefox
xml-result: C://Users/Desktop/Selenise/XMLReport
html-result: C://Users/Desktop/Selenise/HTMLReport
```

and this command to execute the execute the jars and reports:

```
set webdriver.gecko.driver=C:\Users\Desktop\geckodriver.exe
set path=%path%;webdriver.gecko.driver;
java -jar cmdJars.jar TestCases\TestCase1.html --config config.txt --driver firefox --firefox "C://Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe"
```

I am getting this error log:

```
[2017-01-17 10:34:38.139 +05:30] [INFO] Start: Selenese Runner 3.0.0
[2017-01-17 10:34:38.357 +05:30] [INFO] Firefox binary: C://Program Files/Mozill
a Firefox/firefox.exe
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set b
y the webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see https://
github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be downloaded from https:
//github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:19
9)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(Drive
rService.java:109)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService.access$000(GeckoDriver
Service.java:37)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExe
cutable(GeckoDriverService.java:95)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(Driver
Service.java:296)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.createCommandExecutor(Firef
oxDriver.java:277)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:2
47)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:2
42)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:1
35)
        at jp.vmi.selenium.webdriver.FirefoxDriverFactory.newInstance(FirefoxDri
verFactory.java:173)
        at jp.vmi.selenium.webdriver.WebDriverManager$Builder.build(WebDriverMan
ager.java:77)
        at jp.vmi.selenium.webdriver.WebDriverManager.get(WebDriverManager.java:
266)
        at jp.vmi.selenium.selenese.Main.setupRunner(Main.java:139)
        at jp.vmi.selenium.selenese.Main.run(Main.java:82)
        at jp.vmi.selenium.selenese.Main.main(Main.java:221)
[2017-01-17 10:34:38.434 +05:30] [INFO] Exit code: 1
```

Also i have set `webdriver.gecko.driver` in the system environment variable.

why am I getting this error even after setting the path of gecko driver.

**Version:
Gecko driver : geckodriver 0.13.0, 
Selenise runner : Selenese Runner 3.0.0**

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the webdriver.gecko.driver System Property is set?

You can pass this as a JVM argument (I had to on Mac since it doesn't really like dots in environment variables):

```
java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=/path/to/geckodriver -jar cmdJars.jar TestCases\TestCase1.html --config config.txt --driver firefox --firefox "C://Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe"
```

Please make sure -D appears before -jar, as above.